# Robustly determining the language spoken in a YouTube video

Tags: youtube-api, google-api-python-client

According to the YouTube API [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#snippet.defaultLanguage), one should be able to determine the language spoken in a YouTube video using the `list` endpoint. In particular, the language code is in the response: `response['items'][0]['snippet']['defaultAudioLanguage']`.

This works in most cases. However, some videos, such as [this one](https://youtu.be/eb6U6UyLq6g), do not have `defaultAudioLanguage` in the `snippet`. Why does this happen and how can I determine the language spoken in the video in such a case?

Comment: that is the only option in the api

Comment: What about using [YouTube Data API v3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3) [Captions: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/captions/list) endpoint? For the mentioned video it mentions `en` for English.

Comment: @BenjaminLoison That means there are captions in English. I want to determine which language is spoken in the video. The two are not always the same.

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo How come the response does not have a piece of information specified in the documentation?

Answer (score 1):

`defaultAudioLanguage` **presumably** refers to whatever the video author has set here in the Youtube Video Details section:

> [image: Language and Captions Certification]

All of these fields are optional.

I'd probably go for [whisper.cpp](https://github.com/ggerganov/whisper.cpp) to detect the spoken language from given audio (downloading the audio for a YouTube video is left as an exercise, but there are tools for that); once you have a video at hand, you can convert it to a 16khz WAV (which is the only format supported by the whisper.cpp `main` tool), and pass `-dl` (quit after detecting language) to the tool:

```
~/b/whisper.cpp $ ffmpeg -i myvideo.mp4 -an -ac 1 -ar 16000 myaudio.wav
~/b/whisper.cpp $ ./main -dl -m models/ggml-medium-q5_0.bin myaudio.wav
[...]
whisper_full_with_state: auto-detected language: fi (p = 0.997451)
[...]
~/b/whisper.cpp $
```

On my machine, this executed in about 2 seconds for an hour-long video.